# Can this be accomplished with an JOIN statement?

Tags: mysql

I have five tables that are fairly similar in structure but different enough that I wanted to have them as separate tables. Essentially, the tables record events in five different "categories" that have some common fields and some other unique fields.

It now appears I need to write a report in which records from all five tables are shown in descending order of the record creation timestamp (standard across all tables). All tables have the common fields I need, things like fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect, etc.

I can't seem to figure out the best way to write a query to select records from all five tables and display them in one table with a column showing the table from which the record came and the values for the common fields, ordered descending by datetime.

Is there any easy way to do this? Do I have to do it with PHP? I am starting to question my original design.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is similar enough to be *queried* together, it's probably similar enough to be *stored* together in *one* table with an extra column to record the *type*, however...

```
select * from (
    select 'table1', timestamp_col, fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect
    from table1 where ...
    UNION ALL
    select 'table2', timestamp_col, fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect
    from table2 where ...
    UNION ALL
    select 'table3', timestamp_col, fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect
    from table3 where ...
    UNION ALL
    select 'table4', timestamp_col, fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect
    from table4 where ...
    UNION ALL
    select 'table5', timestamp_col, fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect
    from table5 where ..
) x
order by timestamp_col desc
```

You could use a single where statement outside the inner query, but it would perform poorly, because *all* the rows of *all* the tables would be unioned. This way, only the rows actually needed are unioned.

Note that `UNION ALL` is a better choice than `UNION`, because `UNION ALL` doesn't sort (with `UNION` the data would be sorted *twice* - once to remove duplicates and again for the order by).

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I am recognizing that these data probably belong with one table with the type differentiation you described. I just want to make sure, though, as I am no DBA by any stretch... is it a good practice to have fields that are only relevant to one type in the table with NULL values for all types that will just ignore that column?

Comment: You're talking about what is generally called "parse data" (tables with many columns that are null). It's "OK" as long as it doesn't get out of hand. Classic design says keep them separate, but practicality says it's a trade off between the convenience of a single table against the hassle/shame of having columns that only apply to some types. I would still chose one table over many because I subscribe the "one size fits all" school of thought, and the convenience aspect can be considerable and should not be discarded in favour of "good design". After all design is for humans, not computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION ALL` statement. So maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect,date, 1 AS type
FROM
  table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect,date, 2 AS type
FROM
  table2
UNION ALL
SELECT
  fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect,date, 3 AS type
FROM
  table3
UNION ALL
SELECT
  fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect,date, 4 AS type
FROM
  table4
UNION ALL
SELECT
  fName, lName, scorePercent, numCorrect,date, 5 AS type
FROM
  table5
ORDER BY date
```